# MySQL Get row data from Update query with LIMIT via stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which updates multiple rows in a table with a variable LIMIT. I need to get data from the updated rows so I know which exact rows got affected. I wrote this simple procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE select_update(IN myId INT, IN myAttr VARCHAR(10), IN myAmount MEDIUMINT)
begin
  SELECT data FROM mytable WHERE id IS NULL AND attr = myAttr LIMIT myAmount;
  UPDATE mytable SET id = myId WHERE id IS NULL AND attr = myAttr LIMIT myAmount;
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Will this SELECT statement always return the exact same rows that the UPDATE statement affects? Is it possible for another user to execute a query while this procedure is running and thus to possibly change the affected rows between the SELECT and UPDATE?

Comment: These are not in a transaction.  It is possible for database changes to occur between the `select` and the `update`.  In other words, this code has race conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what if I call the procedure from within a transaction?

Comment: The `LIMIT` parameter has to be a literal, you can't use a variable there. Also, `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` returns unpredictable results, there's no guarantee that the `SELECT` and `UPDATE` will process the same rows.

Comment: If it's in a transaction, add the `FOR UPDATE` clause to the `SELECT` query so it will lock all the rows it searches.

Comment: @Barmar, "Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: OK, I stand corrected there, but you still need ORDER BY

Comment: A better solution would be to create a temporary table with the IDs of the rows to be updated. Then you can update those rows and then return the data.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but both the SELECT and UPDATE statements in this procedure have a syntax error: `AND LIMIT`

Comment: @BillKarwin yes thank you, I made some mistakes when changing my code for this example. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary table to hold the primary keys of the rows to be updated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_update(IN myId INT, IN myAttr VARCHAR(10), IN myAmount MEDIUMINT)
begin
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_mytable AS
  SELECT pk FROM mytable WHERE id IS NULL AND attr = myAttr LIMIT myamnt;
  UPDATE mytable JOIN temp_mytable USING (pk)
  SET mytable.id = myId;
  SELECT mytable.data
  FROM mytable JOIN temp_mytable USING (pk);
end$$
```

Comment: Do you prefer this solution over using `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? Also, we don't need `ORDER BY` with this solution right?

Comment: This ensures that it will update the same rows that it selects, without needing a transaction. And we don't need ORDER BY here if we don't care which rows it updates.